# Uploading codeignator function stop working after move to the server

Tags: codeigniter-3

I wrote a function that uploads images to a folder on the server. The function was working properly prior to uploading the project. However, after uploading, I discovered that the controller uploads the image into a single folder [defects img] while bypassing the [main images,thumbs].

According to that, I tested the controller in a variety of machines and found it to be functional.

So I checked the folder permissions and gave the folder full permissions, but it's still not working.

i'm using xampp v3.3.0 which installed on windows server 2012

Controller

```
   function post() {
    ini_set('post_max_size','99500M');
    ini_set('upload_max_size','100000M');
    ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
    ini_set('max_execution_time','5000');

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $head_id = $this->input->post('headid');
    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . './defects_img/';
    $config['new_path'] = FCPATH . './defects_img/thumbs/';
    $config['new_paths'] = FCPATH . './defects_img/main_images/';
    if (!is_dir($config['upload_path'])) {
        mkdir($config['upload_path'], 0777, TRUE);
    }
    if (!is_dir($config['new_path'])) {
        mkdir($config['new_path'], 0777, TRUE);
    }
    if (!is_dir($config['new_paths'])) {
        mkdir($config['new_paths'], 0777, TRUE);
    }
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|bmp|jpeg|PNG';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
    $config['max_size'] = '3072';
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $file_data = $this->upload->data();
        $filename = $file_data['file_name'];
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = './defects_img/' . $filename;

        // Resize the image for thumbnail
        $thumb_filename = preg_replace('/_thumb/', '', $filename);
        $thumb_path = 'defects_img/thumbs/' . $thumb_filename;

        $config['new_image'] = $thumb_path;
        //$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width'] = 100;
        $config['height'] = 100;
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

        // Clear the configuration settings before resizing the main image
        $this->image_lib->clear();

        // Resize the image for main image
        $main_image_filename = $filename;
        $main_image_path = 'defects_img/main_images/' . $main_image_filename;
        $config['new_image'] = $main_image_path;
        $config['width'] = 1000;
        $config['height'] = 1000;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $this->m->post($filename, $head_id);
        //unlink('./defects_img/'. $file_data['file_name']);
        redirect('InspectionBoard/ViewTransaction/' . $head_id, 'refresh');
    }else{
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        //redirect('InspectionBoard/ViewTransaction/' . $head_id, 'refresh');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was unable to upload images was due to the GD library not being active on the server. After enabling the library, I was able to upload images without any issues. [Here an example activating GD library](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-php-gd-in-windows/)